# Only two out of five possible show up when parsing nested json with php

Tags: php, json, parsing, nested

I have a small problem when i try to parse my json. My loop only run two times when i know by manually checking the json that it is supposed to be five matches. So the thing i am wondering is what can i do to get this right? Thanks in advance for any help that i can get.

Here is my php code:

```
$url = "https://example.com";
$result = file_get_contents($url);
  // Will dump a beauty json :3
  $decoded = json_decode($result);
  $comments = $decoded->tournaments[0]->events;
  foreach($comments as $comment){
     $homeTeam = $comment->homeTeam->name;
     $homeScore = $comment->homeScore->current;
     $awayTeam = $comment->awayTeam->name;
     $awayScore = $comment->awayScore->current;
     $status = $comment->status->type;
     //do something with it
     echo $homeTeam;
     echo "</br>";
     echo $homeScore;
     echo "</br>";
     echo $awayTeam;
     echo "</br>";
     echo $awayScore;
     echo "</br>";
     echo $status;
     echo "</br>";
  }
```

This is my output:

```
Skjern Handbold
24
GOG Handbold
23
finished
Aalborg Handbold
32
Skjern Handbold
24
finished
```

And here is an example of the json(sorry but i think i'm not allowed to share the source.)

```
{  
   "sport":{  
      "name":"Handball",
      "slug":"handball",
      "id":6
   },
   "rows":1,
   "tournaments":[  
      {  
         "tournament":{  
            "name":"Handboldligaen Qualification Round, Group 1",
            "slug":"handboldligaen-qualification-round-group-1",
            "id":10600,
            "uniqueId":157,
            "uniqueName":"Handboldligaen",
            "hasEventPlayerStatistics":false,
            "hasEventPlayerHeatMap":false
         },
         "category":{  
            "name":"Denmark",
            "slug":"denmark",
            "priority":0,
            "id":59,
            "flag":"denmark"
         },
         "season":{  
            "name":"Handboldligaen 16\/17",
            "slug":"handboldligaen-1617",
            "year":"16\/17",
            "id":12321
         },
         "hasEventPlayerStatistics":false,
         "hasEventPlayerHeatMap":false,
         "events":[  
            {  
               "sport":{  
                  "name":"Handball",
                  "slug":"handball",
                  "id":6
               },
               "roundInfo":{  
                  "round":5
               },
               "customId":"FGbsNGb",
               "status":{  
                  "code":100,
                  "type":"finished"
               },
               "winnerCode":1,
               "homeTeam":{  
                  "name":"Skjern Handbold",
                  "slug":"skjern-handbold",
                  "gender":"M",
                  "id":4080,
                  "subTeams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "awayTeam":{  
                  "name":"GOG Handbold",
                  "slug":"gog-handbold",
                  "gender":"M",
                  "id":4088,
                  "subTeams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "homeScore":{  
                  "current":24,
                  "period1":12,
                  "normaltime":24
               },
               "awayScore":{  
                  "current":23,
                  "period1":13,
                  "normaltime":23
               },
               "time":{  

               },
               "changes":{  
                  "changeDate":"2017-04-26T20:07:28+00:00",
                  "changes":[  
                     "status.code",
                     "status.description",
                     "status.type",
                     "homeScore.normaltime",
                     "awayScore.normaltime"
                  ],
                  "changeTimestamp":1493237248,
                  "hasExpired":true,
                  "hasHomeChanges":false,
                  "hasAwayChanges":false
               },
               "hasHighlights":false,
               "hasHighlightsStream":false,
               "id":7380204,
               "hasStatistics":true,
               "name":"Skjern Handbold - GOG Handbold",
               "startTime":"18:30",
               "formatedStartDate":"26.04.2017.",
               "startTimestamp":1493231400,
               "statusDescription":"FT",
               "slug":"gog-handbold-skjern-handbold",
               "uniqueTournamentId":157,
               "hasLineups":false,
               "hasLineupsList":false,
               "hasOdds":true,
               "hasLiveOdds":true,
               "hasSubScore":false,
               "hasAggregatedScore":false,
               "hasFirstToServe":false,
               "hasDraw":true,
               "votingEnabled":false,
               "hasTime":false,
               "isSyncable":true,
               "confirmedLineups":false
            },
            {  
               "sport":{  
                  "name":"Handball",
                  "slug":"handball",
                  "id":6
               },
               "roundInfo":{  
                  "round":6
               },
               "customId":"FGbsKGb",
               "status":{  
                  "code":100,
                  "type":"finished"
               },
               "winnerCode":1,
               "homeTeam":{  
                  "name":"Aalborg Handbold",
                  "slug":"aalborg-handbold",
                  "gender":"M",
                  "id":4085,
                  "subTeams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "awayTeam":{  
                  "name":"Skjern Handbold",
                  "slug":"skjern-handbold",
                  "gender":"M",
                  "id":4080,
                  "subTeams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "homeScore":{  
                  "current":32,
                  "period1":18,
                  "normaltime":32
               },
               "awayScore":{  
                  "current":24,
                  "period1":13,
                  "normaltime":24
               },
               "time":{  

               },
               "changes":{  
                  "changeDate":"2017-04-30T17:58:53+00:00",
                  "changes":[  
                     "status.code",
                     "status.description",
                     "status.type",
                     "homeScore.normaltime",
                     "awayScore.normaltime"
                  ],
                  "changeTimestamp":1493575133,
                  "hasExpired":true,
                  "hasHomeChanges":false,
                  "hasAwayChanges":false
               },
               "hasHighlights":false,
               "hasHighlightsStream":false,
               "id":7380206,
               "hasStatistics":true,
               "name":"Aalborg Handbold - Skjern Handbold",
               "startTime":"16:30",
               "formatedStartDate":"30.04.2017.",
               "startTimestamp":1493569800,
               "statusDescription":"FT",
               "slug":"aalborg-handbold-skjern-handbold",
               "uniqueTournamentId":157,
               "hasLineups":false,
               "hasLineupsList":false,
               "hasOdds":true,
               "hasLiveOdds":false,
               "hasSubScore":false,
               "hasAggregatedScore":false,
               "hasFirstToServe":false,
               "hasDraw":true,
               "votingEnabled":false,
               "hasTime":false,
               "isSyncable":true,
               "confirmedLineups":false
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "tournament":{  
            "name":"Handboldligaen, Playoffs",
            "slug":"handboldligaen-playoffs",
            "id":5918,
            "uniqueId":157,
            "uniqueName":"Handboldligaen",
            "hasEventPlayerStatistics":false,
            "hasEventPlayerHeatMap":false
         },
         "category":{  
            "name":"Denmark",
            "slug":"denmark",
            "priority":0,
            "id":59,
            "flag":"denmark"
         },
         "season":{  
            "name":"Handboldligaen 16\/17",
            "slug":"handboldligaen-1617",
            "year":"16\/17",
            "id":12321
         },
         "hasEventPlayerStatistics":false,
         "hasEventPlayerHeatMap":false,
         "events":[  
            {  
               "sport":{  
                  "name":"Handball",
                  "slug":"handball",
                  "id":6
               },
               "roundInfo":{  
                  "round":2,
                  "name":"Semifinals"
               },
               "customId":"FGbsnFE",
               "status":{  
                  "code":100,
                  "type":"finished"
               },
               "winnerCode":1,
               "homeTeam":{  
                  "name":"Skjern Handbold",
                  "slug":"skjern-handbold",
                  "gender":"M",
                  "id":4080,
                  "subTeams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "awayTeam":{  
                  "name":"Ribe-Esbjerg HH",
                  "slug":"ribe-esbjerg-hh",
                  "gender":"M",
                  "id":74013,
                  "subTeams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "homeScore":{  
                  "current":26,
                  "period1":13,
                  "normaltime":26
               },
               "awayScore":{  
                  "current":24,
                  "period1":12,
                  "normaltime":24
               },
               "time":{  

               },
               "changes":{  
                  "changeDate":"2017-05-11T20:10:09+00:00",
                  "changes":[  
                     "status.code",
                     "status.description",
                     "status.type",
                     "homeScore.normaltime",
                     "awayScore.normaltime"
                  ],
                  "changeTimestamp":1494533409,
                  "hasExpired":true,
                  "hasHomeChanges":false,
                  "hasAwayChanges":false
               },
               "hasHighlights":false,
               "hasHighlightsStream":false,
               "id":7406145,
               "hasStatistics":true,
               "name":"Skjern Handbold - Ribe-Esbjerg HH",
               "startTime":"18:30",
               "formatedStartDate":"11.05.2017.",
               "startTimestamp":1494527400,
               "statusDescription":"FT",
               "slug":"ribe-esbjerg-hh-skjern-handbold",
               "uniqueTournamentId":157,
               "hasLineups":false,
               "hasLineupsList":false,
               "hasOdds":true,
               "hasLiveOdds":true,
               "hasSubScore":false,
               "hasAggregatedScore":false,
               "hasFirstToServe":false,
               "hasDraw":true,
               "votingEnabled":false,
               "hasTime":false,
               "isSyncable":true,
               "confirmedLineups":false
            },
            {  
               "sport":{  
                  "name":"Handball",
                  "slug":"handball",
                  "id":6
               },
               "roundInfo":{  
                  "round":2,
                  "name":"Semifinals"
               },
               "customId":"FGbsnFE",
               "status":{  
                  "code":100,
                  "type":"finished"
               },
               "winnerCode":2,
               "homeTeam":{  
                  "name":"Ribe-Esbjerg HH",
                  "slug":"ribe-esbjerg-hh",
                  "gender":"M",
                  "id":74013,
                  "subTeams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "awayTeam":{  
                  "name":"Skjern Handbold",
                  "slug":"skjern-handbold",
                  "gender":"M",
                  "id":4080,
                  "subTeams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "homeScore":{  
                  "current":26,
                  "period1":12,
                  "normaltime":26
               },
               "awayScore":{  
                  "current":31,
                  "period1":18,
                  "normaltime":31
               },
               "time":{  

               },
               "changes":{  
                  "changeDate":"2017-05-14T15:48:53+00:00",
                  "changes":[  
                     "status.code",
                     "status.description",
                     "status.type",
                     "homeScore.normaltime",
                     "awayScore.normaltime"
                  ],
                  "changeTimestamp":1494776933,
                  "hasExpired":true,
                  "hasHomeChanges":false,
                  "hasAwayChanges":false
               },
               "hasHighlights":false,
               "hasHighlightsStream":false,
               "id":7406146,
               "hasStatistics":true,
               "name":"Ribe-Esbjerg HH - Skjern Handbold",
               "startTime":"14:10",
               "formatedStartDate":"14.05.2017.",
               "startTimestamp":1494771000,
               "statusDescription":"FT",
               "slug":"ribe-esbjerg-hh-skjern-handbold",
               "uniqueTournamentId":157,
               "hasLineups":false,
               "hasLineupsList":false,
               "hasOdds":true,
               "hasLiveOdds":true,
               "hasSubScore":false,
               "hasAggregatedScore":false,
               "hasFirstToServe":false,
               "hasDraw":true,
               "votingEnabled":false,
               "hasTime":false,
               "isSyncable":true,
               "confirmedLineups":false
            },
            {  
               "sport":{  
                  "name":"Handball",
                  "slug":"handball",
                  "id":6
               },
               "roundInfo":{  
                  "round":1,
                  "name":"Final"
               },
               "customId":"FGbsKGb",
               "status":{  
                  "code":100,
                  "type":"finished"
               },
               "winnerCode":3,
               "homeTeam":{  
                  "name":"Aalborg Handbold",
                  "slug":"aalborg-handbold",
                  "gender":"M",
                  "id":4085,
                  "subTeams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "awayTeam":{  
                  "name":"Skjern Handbold",
                  "slug":"skjern-handbold",
                  "gender":"M",
                  "id":4080,
                  "subTeams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "homeScore":{  
                  "current":26,
                  "period1":14,
                  "normaltime":26
               },
               "awayScore":{  
                  "current":26,
                  "period1":11,
                  "normaltime":26
               },
               "time":{  

               },
               "changes":{  
                  "changeDate":"2017-05-25T15:51:05+00:00",
                  "changes":[  
                     "status.code",
                     "status.description",
                     "status.type",
                     "homeScore.normaltime",
                     "awayScore.normaltime"
                  ],
                  "changeTimestamp":1495727465,
                  "hasExpired":true,
                  "hasHomeChanges":false,
                  "hasAwayChanges":false
               },
               "hasHighlights":false,
               "hasHighlightsStream":false,
               "id":7416916,
               "hasStatistics":true,
               "name":"Aalborg Handbold - Skjern Handbold",
               "startTime":"14:10",
               "formatedStartDate":"25.05.2017.",
               "startTimestamp":1495721400,
               "statusDescription":"FT",
               "slug":"aalborg-handbold-skjern-handbold",
               "uniqueTournamentId":157,
               "hasLineups":false,
               "hasLineupsList":false,
               "hasOdds":true,
               "hasLiveOdds":true,
               "hasSubScore":false,
               "hasAggregatedScore":false,
               "hasFirstToServe":false,
               "hasDraw":true,
               "votingEnabled":false,
               "hasTime":false,
               "isSyncable":true,
               "confirmedLineups":false
            },
            {  
               "sport":{  
                  "name":"Handball",
                  "slug":"handball",
                  "id":6
               },
               "roundInfo":{  
                  "round":1,
                  "name":"Final"
               },
               "customId":"FGbsKGb",
               "status":{  
                  "code":100,
                  "type":"finished"
               },
               "winnerCode":2,
               "homeTeam":{  
                  "name":"Skjern Handbold",
                  "slug":"skjern-handbold",
                  "gender":"M",
                  "id":4080,
                  "subTeams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "awayTeam":{  
                  "name":"Aalborg Handbold",
                  "slug":"aalborg-handbold",
                  "gender":"M",
                  "id":4085,
                  "subTeams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "homeScore":{  
                  "current":25,
                  "period1":10,
                  "normaltime":25
               },
               "awayScore":{  
                  "current":32,
                  "period1":14,
                  "normaltime":32
               },
               "time":{  

               },
               "changes":{  
                  "changeDate":"2017-05-28T15:47:33+00:00",
                  "changes":[  
                     "status.code",
                     "status.description",
                     "status.type",
                     "homeScore.normaltime",
                     "awayScore.normaltime"
                  ],
                  "changeTimestamp":1495986453,
                  "hasExpired":true,
                  "hasHomeChanges":false,
                  "hasAwayChanges":false
               },
               "hasHighlights":false,
               "hasHighlightsStream":false,
               "id":7416915,
               "hasStatistics":true,
               "name":"Skjern Handbold - Aalborg Handbold",
               "startTime":"14:10",
               "formatedStartDate":"28.05.2017.",
               "startTimestamp":1495980600,
               "statusDescription":"FT",
               "slug":"aalborg-handbold-skjern-handbold",
               "uniqueTournamentId":157,
               "hasLineups":false,
               "hasLineupsList":false,
               "hasOdds":true,
               "hasLiveOdds":true,
               "hasSubScore":false,
               "hasAggregatedScore":false,
               "hasFirstToServe":false,
               "hasDraw":true,
               "votingEnabled":false,
               "hasTime":false,
               "isSyncable":true,
               "confirmedLineups":false
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "tournament":{  
            "name":"Cup",
            "slug":"cup",
            "id":244,
            "uniqueId":1319,
            "uniqueName":"Cup",
            "hasEventPlayerStatistics":false,
            "hasEventPlayerHeatMap":false
         },
         "category":{  
            "name":"Denmark",
            "slug":"denmark",
            "priority":0,
            "id":59,
            "flag":"denmark"
         },
         "season":{  
            "name":"Cup 17\/18",
            "slug":"cup-1718",
            "year":"17\/18",
            "id":14155
         },
         "hasEventPlayerStatistics":false,
         "hasEventPlayerHeatMap":false,
         "events":[  
            {  
               "sport":{  
                  "name":"Handball",
                  "slug":"handball",
                  "id":6
               },
               "roundInfo":{  
                  "round":4,
                  "name":"1\/8"
               },
               "customId":"FGbsQpM",
               "status":{  
                  "code":100,
                  "type":"finished"
               },
               "winnerCode":2,
               "homeTeam":{  
                  "name":"Sydhavsoerne",
                  "slug":"sydhavsoerne",
                  "gender":"M",
                  "id":93291,
                  "subTeams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "awayTeam":{  
                  "name":"Skjern Handbold",
                  "slug":"skjern-handbold",
                  "gender":"M",
                  "id":4080,
                  "subTeams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "homeScore":{  
                  "current":21,
                  "period1":12,
                  "normaltime":21
               },
               "awayScore":{  
                  "current":31,
                  "period1":16,
                  "normaltime":31
               },
               "time":{  

               },
               "changes":{  
                  "changes":[  

                  ],
                  "changeTimestamp":0,
                  "hasExpired":true,
                  "hasHomeChanges":false,
                  "hasAwayChanges":false
               },
               "hasHighlights":false,
               "hasHighlightsStream":false,
               "id":7538722,
               "hasStatistics":false,
               "name":"Sydhavsoerne - Skjern Handbold",
               "startTime":"17:30",
               "formatedStartDate":"23.08.2017.",
               "startTimestamp":1503509400,
               "statusDescription":"FT",
               "slug":"sydhavsoerne-skjern-handbold",
               "uniqueTournamentId":1319,
               "hasLineups":false,
               "hasLineupsList":false,
               "hasOdds":true,
               "hasLiveOdds":false,
               "hasSubScore":false,
               "hasAggregatedScore":false,
               "hasFirstToServe":false,
               "hasDraw":true,
               "votingEnabled":false,
               "hasTime":false,
               "isSyncable":true,
               "confirmedLineups":false
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "tournament":{  
            "name":"Super Cup",
            "slug":"super-cup",
            "id":17307,
            "uniqueId":10493,
            "uniqueName":"Super Cup",
            "hasEventPlayerStatistics":false,
            "hasEventPlayerHeatMap":false
         },
         "category":{  
            "name":"Denmark",
            "slug":"denmark",
            "priority":0,
            "id":59,
            "flag":"denmark"
         },
         "season":{  
            "name":"Super Cup 2017",
            "slug":"super-cup-2017",
            "year":"2017",
            "id":14279
         },
         "hasEventPlayerStatistics":false,
         "hasEventPlayerHeatMap":false,
         "events":[  
            {  
               "sport":{  
                  "name":"Handball",
                  "slug":"handball",
                  "id":6
               },
               "roundInfo":{  
                  "round":1,
                  "name":"Final"
               },
               "customId":"FGbsKGb",
               "status":{  
                  "code":100,
                  "type":"finished"
               },
               "winnerCode":1,
               "homeTeam":{  
                  "name":"Skjern Handbold",
                  "slug":"skjern-handbold",
                  "gender":"M",
                  "id":4080,
                  "subTeams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "awayTeam":{  
                  "name":"Aalborg Handbold",
                  "slug":"aalborg-handbold",
                  "gender":"M",
                  "id":4085,
                  "subTeams":[  

                  ]
               },
               "homeScore":{  
                  "current":27,
                  "period1":13,
                  "normaltime":27
               },
               "awayScore":{  
                  "current":17,
                  "period1":10,
                  "normaltime":17
               },
               "time":{  

               },
               "changes":{  
                  "changeDate":"2017-08-29T20:03:46+00:00",
                  "changes":[  
                     "status.code",
                     "status.description",
                     "status.type",
                     "homeScore.normaltime",
                     "awayScore.normaltime",
                     "homeScore.current"
                  ],
                  "changeTimestamp":1504037026,
                  "hasExpired":true,
                  "hasHomeChanges":false,
                  "hasAwayChanges":false
               },
               "hasHighlights":false,
               "hasHighlightsStream":false,
               "id":7552114,
               "hasStatistics":false,
               "name":"Skjern Handbold - Aalborg Handbold",
               "startTime":"18:30",
               "formatedStartDate":"29.08.2017.",
               "startTimestamp":1504031400,
               "statusDescription":"FT",
               "slug":"aalborg-handbold-skjern-handbold",
               "uniqueTournamentId":10493,
               "hasLineups":false,
               "hasLineupsList":false,
               "hasOdds":true,
               "hasLiveOdds":true,

            }
         ]
      }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your question.

First of all, the json given in example is not fully valid:

There is an extra comma after the last

```
"hasLiveOdds":true,
```

and some extra brackets:

```
     ]
  }
     ]
  }
```

Once fixed, and if I understand your idea, I find 8 matches instead of 5.

Whatever, here is my suggestion:

```
$decoded = json_decode($result);
$tournaments = $decoded->tournaments;
foreach ($tournaments as $tournament) {
    $comments = $tournament->events;
    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You understood i perfectly! Yeah i had to kill a couple of  the brackets to get it to fit sorry if it made helping me harder. Thanks again!